# Crash Reporting Tool for MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, crash-reports

Is there any crash reporting tool that works with Monotouch?

I have tried  Crashlytics but i am not getting the crash reports though my app is added to Crashlytics.

Any other crash reporting tool people tried which works best with MonoTouch (4.2.2)?

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the TestFlight SDK. They allow you to beta test your product and have an API that collect crash reports and other metrics.

Comment: I believe TestFlight is mostly for the testing purpose. I am looking for something while in production. My app is an enterprise app so i can't also relay on App store for crash reports.

Comment: Take a look on the production version of their API [FlightPath](https://testflightapp.com/flightpath/). There is a solution to migrate from teh TestFlight SDK on Beta testing to a productiojn API.